# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from tab crashed in Python with Odoo, But selenium working fine alone

Tags: python, selenium, odoo-12

I know this is a duplicate question and answered by the community, but those answers won't work for me. Here I am using the selenium in odoo application and when I run that odoo application, selenium webdriver.Chrome() failed to create a session and the new browser window just appear and close.

The version of driver is : ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) and Chrome browser version is: Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 664, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 345, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 338, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 909, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 510, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1323, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1311, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/api.py", line 395, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/api.py", line 382, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/custom_modules_13/testing/models/models.py", line 61, in send_whatsapp_message
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

Comment: Those answers are not the solutions.

Comment: Did you try out anything from those solutions? Can you update the question with your code trials?

Comment: Yes I tried all of them, But not working.

Comment: Please re-open my question.